# Flutter app User data size is very large 60 MB

Tags: android, sqlite, flutter

I am developing a flutter android/IOS application. 
For now, I am developing on android only.

I use SQLite to store DB from internet. 
The app size is 90 MB now and that is the debug version which is normal for flutter. But the app User data is 60 MB. In addition to the 90 MB of the app, the app uses 150 MB.

What makes the user data become large?

Edit 1:

[image: Screenshot]

Edit2:
I created a new flutter app and the app user data is 30 MB (just the counter example with no edit)!!?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using caches too much with big images or something that would use big data, and if you are building bundle apk you can reduce size of your apk with split-per-abi see [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#build-an-apk)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. for the apk size, you are right. i cleared the cache with no change. the cache storage is separated from the User data part in space used in settings.

Comment: I added a screenshot in the question.

Answer (score 0):

the debug apk is always bulky. try to build release apk.

```
flutter build apk --release
```

read [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

your application is in on debug mode so absolutely it will be huge size
you should change your application to realize mode you can do that by applying this steps :
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android
recently my application drop down from 100Mb to 20Mb which is very normal 
another things can change your application performance and size is if you are opening streams and not disposing it

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to do that now, but I have an error                     
`Failed to transform libs.jar to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Failed to transform 'E:\App\build\app\intermediates\flutter\profile\libs.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: FileNotFoundException,`

Comment: you have to do few steps first of all you need to do the steps in the link,
once you finish you are going to use the terminal to use the flutter build apk --release but befor you do you need to cd to the current flutter project after that you can use the command

Comment: I will try it now.